# My Regular Expression pattern does not work

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write regular expression for the following pattern in javascript but it is not working. Please can someone advise?

Pattern: ",anyONELetter,"

Sample string

```
James Yashiro,a,b,c Dean J Loza,a,b
```

Required string:

```
James Yashiro, Andrew J Loza
```

My javascript:

```
var string = string.replace(/[,^a-z{1},]/gi, '');
```

Comment: You are mixing character classes and sequences of characters in a regex. Try `/,[a-z],/gi`. Please provide a sample string and expected output for testing/demo.

Comment: please see above edit as requested

Comment: How can you get `Hanako Yashiro', Andrew J Loza` from `James Yashiro,a,b,c Dean J Loza,a,b`? It is impossible without more clarifications. Why "James" must be replaced with "Hanako"? There must be some list.

Comment: sorry mistake. corrected

Comment: Please read basic documentation on regexps.

Comment: not very helpful. but thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code doesn't work? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I guess `Dean J Loza,a,b` --> `Dean J Loza`, not `Andrew J Loza`. Please update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything inside a pair of unescaped `[...]` is treated as one symbol. `[\s*]` matches 1 whitespace or `*` character. Your `[,^a-z{1},]` regex matches 1 symbol that is either a `,` or `^`, ASCII letter, `{`, or `1`, or `}` or a comma.

You need the following regex to replace all the `,`+standalone letter patterns with `,`:

```
/(?:,[a-z]\b)+,*/gi
```

And replace with one `,`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uQ7aC3/3)

The `(?:,[a-z]\b)+,*` matches one or more sequence of:

- `,` a comma followed with
- `[a-z]\b` - an ASCII letter (as a whole word because of `\b` after it)

followed with zero or more commas (`,*`).

Then, you will need to trim trailing `,` symbols from the string with another regex:

```
.replace(/,+$/, '')
```

The `,+$` matches one or more commas at the end of the string (`$` asserts the position at the end of the string, so the commas inside the string will be kept intact).

JS demo:

```js
var s = 'James Yashiro,a,b,c, Dean J Loza,a,b';
var res = s.replace(/(?:,[a-z]\b)+,*/gi, ',').replace(/,+$/, '');
document.write(res);
```

Comment: perfect. Thank you. that's some serious coding voodoo.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try a regex like this one:

```
/(,[a-z],*?)/gi
```

and replace with an empty string.

Example:

```js
var test = 'James Yashiro,a,b,c, Dean J Loza,a,b';
var result = test.replace(/(,[a-z],*?)/gi, '');
document.write(result);
```